# Trying to map through returned data after a form submit. NextJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, next.js

I'm currently messing around with a couple game API's, I've setup a simple form to send a get request with query's to an API route that talks to the game server.

Currently it works great however if I try to map through the response after the form is submitted, I get an error that the map is not a function `TypeError: stats.data.data.stats.all.map is not a function`

##### Screenshot of issue

[image: error screenshot]

I've put the code for the component below, Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { VStack, Container, FormControl, FormLabel , Input, Button, Select, HStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const Index = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [accountType, setAccountType] = React.useState("");
  const [timeWindow, setTimeWindow] = React.useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState("");
  const [stats, setStats] = React.useState(null)
  const [err, setErr] = React.useState(null)

  const getuserData = async () => {
    axios.get(`/api/getStats?name=${name}&accountType=${accountType}&timeWindow=${timeWindow}&image=${image}`, {
           headers: {
             Accept: "application/json",
           },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setStats(response.data)
      }
      )
      .then((response) => {
  
        console.log('console log of prop', stats)
        console.log('client side log',  response.data);
        console.log('client side log data.data',  response.data.data);
        console.log('client side repsonse log', response)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setErr(err.message)
      });
    };
    

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     getuserData();
  };

  console.log(stats)

  return (
     <React.Fragment>
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <FormControl>
         <HStack>
          <FormLabel >Enter Account Name: </FormLabel>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              required
              value={name}
              placeholder="account name"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
          
            <FormLabel >Account Type: </FormLabel>
              <Select
              required
              placeholder='Select Account Type'
              onChange={(e) => setAccountType(e.target.value)}
              >
                <option value='epic'>PC</option>
                <option value='psn'>Playstation</option>
                <option value='xbl'>Xbox</option>
            </Select>

           <FormLabel >Time Played: </FormLabel>
              <Select
              required
              placeholder='Select Window of Time Played'
              onChange={(e) => setTimeWindow(e.target.value)}
              >
                <option value='season'>season</option>
                <option value='lifetime'>lifetime</option>
            </Select>

            <FormLabel>Select Platform</FormLabel>
            <Select
                required
                placeholder='Select The Platform You Play On!'
                onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option value='all'>All</option>
                  <option value='keyboardMouse '>Keyboard & Mouse</option>
                  <option value='gamepad'>Controller</option>
                  <option value='touch'>Mobile</option>
                  <option value='none'>None</option>
              </Select>
              </HStack>
          </FormControl>
           <Button type="submit" colorScheme="green" m="2">Search</Button>
           
        </form>

        {console.log('after form', stats)}
        {console.log('status', stats && stats.data.status)}
        {console.log('stats solo', stats && stats.data.data.stats.all.solo)}

        <VStack>
          <Container>
          <img width="1000" height="1000" src={stats?.data.data.image} />

          {/*   {stats && stats.data.status.includes(200) ? (
         <img width="1000" height="1000" src={stats?.data.data.image} /> 
            ) : (
              <div>Error. Check your details are correct!</div>
            )
          } */}

        {stats && stats.data.data.stats.all.map((stat =>
            <code>{stat.solo.kills}</code>
        ))} 

          </Container>
        </VStack>
    </React.Fragment>
 );
};

export default Index;
```

##### Raw json from debugger

// I did have to comment out the map in order for the response to comeback it. Not sure if that could also be

```
{
"data": {
    "data": {
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "account": {
                "id": "9a8cc59adfff4f61902a11141b8c1d0e",
                "name": "notCarried"
            },
            "battlePass": {
                "level": 23,
                "progress": 68
            },
            "image": "https://cdn.fortnite-api.com/stats/v2/d5875d6387983eaec7cc6fbfac706c1b0eb0527f.png",
            "stats": {
                "all": {
                    "overall": {
                        "score": 143447,
                        "scorePerMin": 10.995,
                        "scorePerMatch": 26.153,
                        "wins": 175,
                        "top3": 57,
                        "top5": 104,
                        "top6": 98,
                        "top10": 623,
                        "top12": 253,
                        "top25": 1163,
                        "kills": 8291,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.635,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.512,
                        "deaths": 5310,
                        "kd": 1.561,
                        "matches": 5485,
                        "winRate": 3.191,
                        "minutesPlayed": 13047,
                        "playersOutlived": 32795,
                        "lastModified": "2022-04-12T11:44:46Z"
                    },
                    "solo": {
                        "score": 52697,
                        "scorePerMin": 22.932,
                        "scorePerMatch": 16.545,
                        "wins": 115,
                        "top10": 623,
                        "top25": 1163,
                        "kills": 5067,
                        "killsPerMin": 2.205,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.591,
                        "deaths": 3070,
                        "kd": 1.65,
                        "matches": 3185,
                        "winRate": 3.611,
                        "minutesPlayed": 2298,
                        "playersOutlived": 19072,
                        "lastModified": "2022-04-10T13:52:22Z"
                    },
                    "duo": {
                        "score": 22598,
                        "scorePerMin": 23.787,
                        "scorePerMatch": 25.249,
                        "wins": 22,
                        "top5": 104,
                        "top12": 253,
                        "kills": 1179,
                        "killsPerMin": 1.241,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.317,
                        "deaths": 873,
                        "kd": 1.351,
                        "matches": 895,
                        "winRate": 2.458,
                        "minutesPlayed": 950,
                        "playersOutlived": 6608,
                        "lastModified": "2022-04-12T11:44:46Z"
                    },
                    "trio": null,
                    "squad": {
                        "score": 10224,
                        "scorePerMin": 22.226,
                        "scorePerMatch": 14.904,
                        "wins": 10,
                        "top3": 57,
                        "top6": 98,
                        "kills": 700,
                        "killsPerMin": 1.522,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.02,
                        "deaths": 676,
                        "kd": 1.036,
                        "matches": 686,
                        "winRate": 1.458,
                        "minutesPlayed": 460,
                        "playersOutlived": 3203,
                        "lastModified": "2021-07-31T15:31:26Z"
                    },
                    "ltm": {
                        "score": 63786,
                        "scorePerMin": 6.637,
                        "scorePerMatch": 85.275,
                        "wins": 28,
                        "kills": 1404,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.146,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.877,
                        "deaths": 720,
                        "kd": 1.95,
                        "matches": 748,
                        "winRate": 3.743,
                        "minutesPlayed": 9611,
                        "playersOutlived": 5667,
                        "lastModified": "2021-07-31T15:31:26Z"
                    }
                },
                "keyboardMouse": {
                    "overall": {
                        "score": 125068,
                        "scorePerMin": 12.034,
                        "scorePerMatch": 163.061,
                        "wins": 8,
                        "top3": 3,
                        "top5": 18,
                        "top6": 9,
                        "top10": 47,
                        "top12": 39,
                        "top25": 111,
                        "kills": 924,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.089,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.205,
                        "deaths": 759,
                        "kd": 1.217,
                        "matches": 767,
                        "winRate": 1.043,
                        "minutesPlayed": 10393,
                        "playersOutlived": 30539,
                        "lastModified": "2022-04-12T11:44:46Z"
                    },
                    "solo": {
                        "score": 48884,
                        "scorePerMin": 22.939,
                        "scorePerMatch": 132.119,
                        "wins": 3,
                        "top10": 47,
                        "top25": 111,
                        "kills": 274,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.129,
                        "killsPerMatch": 0.741,
                        "deaths": 367,
                        "kd": 0.747,
                        "matches": 370,
                        "winRate": 0.811,
                        "minutesPlayed": 2131,
                        "playersOutlived": 17621,
                        "lastModified": "2022-04-10T13:52:22Z"
                    },
                    "duo": {
                        "score": 21964,
                        "scorePerMin": 23.848,
                        "scorePerMatch": 184.571,
                        "wins": 4,
                        "top5": 18,
                        "top12": 39,
                        "kills": 173,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.188,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.454,
                        "deaths": 115,
                        "kd": 1.504,
                        "matches": 119,
                        "winRate": 3.361,
                        "minutesPlayed": 921,
                        "playersOutlived": 6349,
                        "lastModified": "2022-04-12T11:44:46Z"
                    },
                    "trio": null,
                    "squad": {
                        "score": 9973,
                        "scorePerMin": 22.361,
                        "scorePerMatch": 169.034,
                        "wins": 0,
                        "top3": 3,
                        "top6": 9,
                        "kills": 84,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.188,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.424,
                        "deaths": 59,
                        "kd": 1.424,
                        "matches": 59,
                        "winRate": 0,
                        "minutesPlayed": 446,
                        "playersOutlived": 3092,
                        "lastModified": "2021-07-31T15:31:26Z"
                    },
                    "ltm": {
                        "score": 50105,
                        "scorePerMin": 6.991,
                        "scorePerMatch": 202.036,
                        "wins": 1,
                        "kills": 452,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.063,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.823,
                        "deaths": 247,
                        "kd": 1.83,
                        "matches": 248,
                        "winRate": 0.403,
                        "minutesPlayed": 7167,
                        "playersOutlived": 5232,
                        "lastModified": "2021-07-31T15:31:26Z"
                    }
                },
                "gamepad": {
                    "overall": {
                        "score": 18379,
                        "scorePerMin": 6.925,
                        "scorePerMatch": 3.896,
                        "wins": 167,
                        "top3": 54,
                        "top5": 86,
                        "top6": 89,
                        "top10": 576,
                        "top12": 214,
                        "top25": 1052,
                        "kills": 7367,
                        "killsPerMin": 2.776,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.561,
                        "deaths": 4551,
                        "kd": 1.619,
                        "matches": 4718,
                        "winRate": 3.54,
                        "minutesPlayed": 2654,
                        "playersOutlived": 2256,
                        "lastModified": "2019-10-17T04:40:24Z"
                    },
                    "solo": {
                        "score": 3813,
                        "scorePerMin": 22.832,
                        "scorePerMatch": 1.355,
                        "wins": 112,
                        "top10": 576,
                        "top25": 1052,
                        "kills": 4793,
                        "killsPerMin": 28.701,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.703,
                        "deaths": 2703,
                        "kd": 1.773,
                        "matches": 2815,
                        "winRate": 3.979,
                        "minutesPlayed": 167,
                        "playersOutlived": 1451,
                        "lastModified": "2019-10-17T04:40:24Z"
                    },
                    "duo": {
                        "score": 634,
                        "scorePerMin": 21.862,
                        "scorePerMatch": 0.817,
                        "wins": 18,
                        "top5": 86,
                        "top12": 214,
                        "kills": 1006,
                        "killsPerMin": 34.69,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.296,
                        "deaths": 758,
                        "kd": 1.327,
                        "matches": 776,
                        "winRate": 2.32,
                        "minutesPlayed": 29,
                        "playersOutlived": 259,
                        "lastModified": "2019-01-12T02:30:20Z"
                    },
                    "trio": null,
                    "squad": {
                        "score": 251,
                        "scorePerMin": 17.929,
                        "scorePerMatch": 0.4,
                        "wins": 10,
                        "top3": 54,
                        "top6": 89,
                        "kills": 616,
                        "killsPerMin": 44,
                        "killsPerMatch": 0.982,
                        "deaths": 617,
                        "kd": 0.998,
                        "matches": 627,
                        "winRate": 1.595,
                        "minutesPlayed": 14,
                        "playersOutlived": 111,
                        "lastModified": "2019-01-18T06:46:27Z"
                    },
                    "ltm": {
                        "score": 13681,
                        "scorePerMin": 5.598,
                        "scorePerMatch": 27.362,
                        "wins": 27,
                        "kills": 952,
                        "killsPerMin": 0.39,
                        "killsPerMatch": 1.904,
                        "deaths": 473,
                        "kd": 2.013,
                        "matches": 500,
                        "winRate": 5.4,
                        "minutesPlayed": 2444,
                        "playersOutlived": 435,
                        "lastModified": "2019-07-14T08:15:54Z"
                    }
                },
                "touch": null
            }
        }
    }
},
"status": 200,
"statusText": "OK",
"headers": {
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Tue, 12 Apr 2022 11:48:19 GMT",
    "etag": "\"1270-feipp1fYiZBY8Zu4RV0p6SZKj8U\"",
    "keep-alive": "timeout=5",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding"
},
"config": {
    "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "/api/getStats?name=notCarried&accountType=epic&timeWindow=lifetime&image=all"
},
"request": {}
```

}

Comment: What's the response from the API call? Could you share the raw JSON format for that response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to map an Array, but the result you are getting is an Object.

try to wrap the result you are tryin to map inside `Object.values()`;

```
let result = Object.values(response.data);
setStats(result);
```

Also, it would be better to get the exact data like this:

```
let result = Object.values(response.data.data.data.stats.all);
setStats(result);
```

so your code will be much cleaner as a result:

```
{stats && stats.map((stat =>
 <code>{stat.solo.kills}</code>
))}
```

Comment: This is working however it is combining each separate platforms solo kills into one which returns `50672744793` However I only want the `solo 5067`. I understand I can't map into an just one of the arrays to only get the 1 platforms solo kills which is the main issue. Doing a bit of research hasn't returned a significant answer

Comment: Great, if you found my answer helpful, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. 
You can also post another question for the other problem you have and I'll try my best to answer it.

Comment: I thought I had sorry thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857914/how-to-properly-map-through-objects-in-react-but-only-show-a-specific-value

Comment: I answered your question you can check.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then((response) => {
    debugger;  // <- watch here what recieves in response data
    setStats(response.data)
}
```

Comment: Yep. Just updated the post! with it